# tengo un problema con pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Acabo de actualizar pycharm community y ahora me dice que windows defender tiene un conflicto con pycharm me dice esto

> "Windows Defender podría estar afectando su compilación y el rendimiento de IDE. PyCharm verificó los siguientes directorios: C: \ Users \ jaimel .jansel \ AppData \ Local \ JetBrains \ PyCharmCE2020.1"

hice lo que me dice y sigue igual[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible causa si el mensaje de error es que Windows no puede asignar un trozo de memoria continua del tamaño necesario. Actualice la configuración de Windows Defender para excluir el directorio de proyecto listado ( `C:\Users\jaimel.jansel\Desktop\api rest` ) del escaneando en tiempo real. Los datos de la aplicación en la carpeta AppData son por defecto una carpeta oculta y el usuario no tendrá acceso a ellos.

Añade una exclusión en Windows Defender. La exclusión de una carpeta se aplicará también a todas las subcarpetas de la misma.

1. Abre Centro de Seguridad de Windows Defender.
2. Ve a Protección contra amenazas y virus.
3. Debajo de Exclusiones, seleccione Agregar o quitar exclusiones.
4. Elige el archivo o la carpeta que quieres quitar exclusiones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]